# Values from dropdownlist yii2

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

[image: This is my scenario]

I want to calculate rollno on runtime on the basis of class and session.
How to get values of class and session in controller without submitting form

Comment: use onchange ajax call.

Comment: why controller? Use **jquery**.

Comment: @G4M1TG

'onchange' => '

                                        $.post("index.php?r=controller/action&param=' . '"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                                            $("select#absc-asas").html( data );
                                        });'

but it is for one field... how to take two dropdownlist values in same actions...?

Comment: @InsaneSkull

i know..but in my situation , i have to use model's value roll no and make it after getting values of class and session from database. So this will only be done in controller

Comment: then go for ajax call suggested by @G4M1TG